# How to write credit in Japanese

Tags: words

By credit, I mean to properly write the name of the contributor on a project. Like how to tell that something is Made in ___, we use -製{せい} as in 日本製{にほんせい}.

Here is one case... In English we can use:
1. Author: John 
2. Written by: John

Point 1 in Japanese might be 作家：John . I guess point 2 would be John によって書かれた (but it sounds like a sentence and not something that is written as a credit. I mean... it's quite long)

And that case only cover about books, how about a broader case such as:
- Originated from:
- Edited by:
- Created by:
- Translated by:
Is there a pattern we could use as a basic guidance?

Comment: Is "(kei)" meant to be furigana of 製?

Comment: ＠broccoli forest ah, I'm sorry, it should be Sei. I have fixed it and properly put the furigana on top of the kanji just now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a customary to use *active voice* when we refer to a work with its contributors for general purposes e.g. on the book cover.

> 地底――地球深部探求の歴史　デイビッド・ホワイトハウス**著**　江口あとか**訳**
>   *[Bookname] **by** David Whitehouse, **translated by** Atoka Eguchi* (seems to be [this book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Journey-Centre-Earth-Remarkable-Scientific/dp/0297608800))

[image]
([source](http://nejiport.tumblr.com/post/135155486448/%E5%9C%B0%E5%BA%95-%E5%9C%B0%E7%90%83%E6%B7%B1%E9%83%A8%E6%8E%A2%E6%B1%82%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2-%E3%83%87%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%83%9B%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9-%E8%91%97-%E6%B1%9F%E5%8F%A3%E3%81%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B-%E8%A8%B3-%E8%A3%85%E4%B8%81%E5%B0%8F%E6%9E%97%E5%89%9Buna))

But for credit use, we prefer noun prefix style (your #1) to indicate them. There's no #2 equivalent with passive voice prefix, because it's grammatically impossible.

> 時計じかけのオレンジ *A Clockwork Orange*
>   著者：アントニイ・バージェス *Author: Anthony Burgess*
>   訳者：乾　信一郎 *Translator: Shin'ichiro Inui*

[image]
([source](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/soorce/20070105))

> ガルム・ウォーズ *Garm Wars*
>   原作・脚本・監督：押井守 *Original work/Scenario/Director: Mamoru Oshii*
>   日本語版プロデューサー：鈴木敏夫 *JP Producer: Toshio Suzuki*
>   宣伝コピー：虚淵玄 *Copywriting: Gen Urobuchi*
>   　︙

[image]
([source](http://garmwars-movie.com/jp/))

---

**PS**

The word 作家 means "writer" as one's profession rather than the role in relation to a work. If what you mean is "author of the work", you have to use 作者 or 著者 (particularly for books/papers). The same applies to 翻訳家 vs. 訳者 (translator), 編集者 vs 編者 (editor) etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think

"Author" is 作者、著者.

"Written by" is 著、著作.

"Originated from" is　原作.

"Edited by" is 編集.

"Translated by" is 訳、翻訳.

"Created by" may be 制作 but I am not sure. They may be producers or publishers or something else.